# How to determine the number of appearances of a letter in a string using C language?

Tags: c

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int appar(char c[], char x);

int main() {
  char c[] = "hello everyone!";
  int b = appar(c, 'h');
  printf("nbr of h is %d ", b);

  return 0;
}

int appar(char c[], char x) {
  int i = 0, cmpt = 0;
  int q = strlen(c);
  for (i; i < q; i++) {
    if (c[i] == 'x')
      cmpt++;
  }
  return cmpt;
}
```

I run and compile the program, but I receive "nbr of h is 0".

What's the wrong in this code?

Comment: `if(c[i]=='x')` compares with the _character_ `'x'`. You mean `if(c[i]==x)` which compares with the _variable_ `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `c[i]=='x'` to `c[i]==x`

You want to compare with the variable x, not the character constant 'x'

Comment: Detail: C identifies `'x'` as a _character constant_ .  C does have literals: _string literal_ and _compound literal_, both of which can have their address taken - not so with `'x'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : Thanks! Changed answer accordingly.